# Composition and Inversion of Control

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I just came across Inversion of Control approach (implemented using Dependency Injection) of designing loosely coupled software architecture. As per my understanding the IOC approach aims to solve problem related to tight coupling between classes by instantiating an object of a class inside another class which should ideally not happen (as per the pattern). Is my understanding correct here?

If above is true than what about composition or has-a relationship (the very basic important aspect of OO). For an example I write my stack class using a linked list class already defined so I instantiate a linked list class inside my stack class. But as per IOC this will result in tight coupling and hence a bad design. Is this true? I am bit confused here between composition or has-a relationship and IOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my doubts as to my understanding of Inversion of Control too. (It seems like an application of good OO design principles given a fancy name) So, let me assume you are a beginner, analyse your example and clarify my thoughts on the path.

We should start by defining an interface `IStack`.

```
interface IStack<T>
{
    bool IsEmpty();
    T Pop();
    void Push(T item);
}
```

In a way we are already finished; the rest of the code probably will not care whether we implemented it with linked lists, or arrays, or whatever. `StackWithLinkedList : IStack` and `StackWithArray : IStack` will behave the same.

```
class StackWithLinkedList<T> : IStack<T>
{
   private LinkedList<T> list;

   public StackWithLinkedList<T>()
   {
      list = new LinkedList<T>();
   }
}
```

So `StackWithLinkedList` totally owns the `list`; it does not need any help from outside to construct it, it does not need any flexibility (that line will never change) and the clients of `StackWithLinkedList` couldn't care less (they have no access to the list). In short, this is not a good example to discuss Inversion of Control: we don't need any.

Let's discuss a similar example, `PriorityQueue<T>` :

```
interface IPriorityQueue<T>
{
    bool IsEmpty();
    T Dequeue();
    void Enqueue(T item);
}
```

Now we have a problem: we need to compare items of type `T` to provide an implementation of a `IPriorityQueue`. Clients still do not care whether we use an array, or a heap or whatever inside, but they do care about how we compare items. We could require `T` to implement `IComparable<T>` but that would be an unnecessary restriction. What we need is some piece of functionality that will compare `T` items by our request:

```
class PriorityQueue<T> : IPriorityQueue<T>
{
   private Func<T,T,int> CompareTo;
   private LinkedList<T> list;
   //bla bla.
}
```

Such that:

- if `CompareTo(left,right) < 0` then left < right (in some sense)
- if `CompareTo(left,right) > 0` then left > right (in some sense)
- if `CompareTo(left,right) = 0` then left = right (in some sense)
- (We would also require `CompareTo` to be consistent, etc. but that's another topic)

The problem is how to initialize `CompareTo`.

One option might be, -let's suppose there is a generic comparison creator somewhere- use the comparison creator. (I agree, the example is becoming a little silly)

```
public PriorityQueue()
{
    this.CompareTo = ComparisonCreator<T>.CreateComparison();
    this.list = new LinkedList<T>();
}
```

Or, perhaps even something like: `ServiceLocator.Instance.ComparisonCreator<T>.CreateComparison();`

This is not an ideal solution for the following reasons:

1. `PriorityQueue` is now (very unnecessarily) dependant on `ComparisonCreator`. If it is on a different assembly, it has to reference it. If someone changes `ComparisonCreator` he has to make sure `PriorityQueue` is not affected.
2. The clients will have a difficult time to use the `PriorityQueue`. They will first need to make sure that the `ComparisonCreator` is constructed and initialized.
3. The clients will have a difficult time to change the default behaviour. Suppose somewhere a client needs a different `CompareTo` function. There is no easy solution. For example, if it changes the `ComparisonCreator<T>`'s behaviour, it may affect other clients. What if there are other threads. Even in a single thread environment the client will probably need to undo the change on construction. It's too much effort just to make it work.
4. For the same reasons, it is difficult to unit test the `PriorityQueue`. One needs to set up the whole environment.

Of course, - and of course you knew this all along - there is a much easier way in this specific problem. Just provide the `CompareTo` function in the constructor:

```
public PriorityQueue(Func<T,T,int> CompareTo)
{
    this.CompareTo = CompareTo;
    this.list = new LinkedList<T>();
}
```

Let's check:

1. `PriorityQueue` is independent of `ComparisonCreator`.
2. For the clients, probably it is much easier to use `PriorityQueue`. They may need to provide a `CompareTo` function, but at the worst case they can always ask the `ServiceLocator`, so al least it is never more difficult.
3. Changing the default behaviour is very easy. Just give a different `CompareTo` function. What one client does, does not affect other clients.
4. It is very easy to unit test `PriorityQueue`. There is no complex environment to set up. We can easily test it with different `CompareTo` functions, etc.

What we did is called "constructor injection" because we injected a dependency in the constructor. By giving the needed dependency at the construction, we were able to change the `PriorityQueue` into a "self sufficient" class. We still create a `LinkedList<T>`, a concrete class in the construction for the same reasons in `Stack` example: it is not a real dependency.

Answer (score 4):

> As per my understanding the IOC approach aims to solve problem related
>   to tight coupling between classes by instantiating an object of a
>   class inside another class which should ideally not happen (as per the
>   pattern). Is my understanding correct here?

Close, but you are slightly off.  The problem of tight coupling is addressed  when you define contracts between classes (interfaces in Java).  Since you need implementations of your contracts(interfaces), at some point those implementations must be provided.  IoC is **one** way of providing an implementation, but not the only way.  So tight coupling is really orthogonal to Inversion of Control (meaning it's not directly related).

More specifically, you can have loose coupling but no IoC.  The IoC part is that the implementations are coming from outside of the components.  Consider the case where you define a class that uses an interface implementation.  When you test that class, you might provide a mock.  When you pass the mock to the class under test, you are not using IoC.  However when you start your app, and the IoC container decides what to pass to your class, **that's the IoC**.

> For an example I write my stack class using a linked list class
>   already defined so I instantiate a linked list class inside my stack
>   class. But as per IOC this will result in tight coupling and hence a
>   bad design. Is this true? I am bit confused here between composition
>   or has-a relationship and IOC.

Yes and No.  In the general sense, you don't need to completely abstract every bit of functionality in your app.  You can, and purists probably would, but it can be tedious and over-done.

In this case, you could treat your stack as a black box, and not manage it with IoC.  Remember, the Stack itself is loosely couple because the Stack's behavior can be abstracted away.  Also, consider the following two definitions

```
class StackImpl implements Stack {
   private List backingList
```

vs

```
class StackImpl implements Stack {
   private LinkedList backingList
```

The first is vastly superior to the second, precisely because it's easier to change List implementations; i.e. you have already provided a loose coupling.

That's as far as I would take it.  Besides, if you are using composition, you can certainly configure most IoC containers (if not all) to pass things to the constructor or invoke setters, so you can still have a **has-A** relationship.

Answer (score 3):

Good implementations of IoC can fulfill the "has a" pattern, but just abstract the implementation of the child.

For example, every business layer class may, by your design, "have a" exception handler; with IoC you can define it so that the exception handler that actually gets instantiated at runtime be different in different environments.

The most value in IoC is if you are doing lots of automated testing; in these scenarios you can instantiate mock data access components in your test environment, but have real data access components instantiated in production, which keeps your tests clean.  The downside of IoC is that it's harder to debug, since everything is more abstract.

Answer (score 1):

The tight coupling in your stack example comes from the stack intantiating a specific list type.  The IOC allows the creator of the stack type to provide which exact list implementation to use (e.g. for performance or testing purposes), realizing that the stack does not (at least should not) care what the exact type of the list is as long as it has a specific interface (the methods that stack wants to use) and the concetere implementation provides the required semantics (e.g. iterating through the list will give access to all elements added to the list in the order they were added).

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding the IOC approach aims to solve problem related
>   to tight coupling between classes by instantiating an object of a
>   class inside another class which should ideally not happen (as per the
>   pattern). Is my understanding correct here?

IoC is actually [quite a broad concept](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html), so let's restrict the field to the Dependency Injection approach that you are referring to. Yes, Dependency Injection does what you said.

I think the reason why `hvgotcodes` thinks that you are slightly off is that the concept of tight coupling can be thought as of having multiple levels. Programming to interfaces is the way to abstract from a particular implementation, which keeps the usage of some piece of code some client code interacts with and its implementation loosely coupled. 
The implementation has to be created (instantiated) somewhere though: even if you program to an interface, if the implementation is created inside the client code you are bound to that particular implementation.

So we can abstract the **implementation** from the interface, but we can also abstract the **choice** of which implementation to use.

As soon as this detail is clear, you have to ask yourself when it makes sense to abstract the choice of the implementation, which is basically one of the fundamental questions of software engineering: when should you abstract what? The answer to the question is of course context dependent.

> But as per IOC this will result in tight coupling and hence a bad
>   design. Is this true?

If tight coupling is bad design, why are you still relying on standard Java classes? We actually need to distinguish between [stable and volatile dependencies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/08/24/718828.aspx).

Citing your example, if you are using the standard implementation of a list, you probably may not want to inject this dependency into your class. What would you achieve by doing this? Do you expect the standard implementation of the list to change any time soon, or do you want to be able to inject a different implementation of a standard list?

On the other hand, suppose you have a custom list with some sort of change tracking mechanism, so that you can perform undo and redo operations on it. Now it could make sense to inject it, because you may want to be able to unit test the client class in isolation, without incurring in potential bugs of your custom list implementation.

As you see, tight coupling is not always bad, sometimes it makes sense, sometimes it is to be avoided: in the end it comes down to the type of dependency.